# What happens when a city-state captures a city that cannot be razed?

Tags: civilization-5

If a city-state captures a city that cannot be razed, what happens?

The examples where this will happen, that I can think of, are:

- An original main-Civ capital under the original owner's control.
- An original main-Civ capital under another Civ's control.
- Another city-state that has been previously captured by another Civ.

Comment: Can city-states even take cities at all?

Comment: @Will Oh yes! I ask this because the third example has *just happened* in my game. Venice has apparently got *slightly* annoyed, and has captured and razed 4 Aztec cities (I've helped with some advanced units for them) before reaching the Aztec-captured Stockholm. I'm giving others a chance to answer, but if no one's posted much before morning I'll add a self-answer with my experiences.

Comment: Wow, I wish my city-state allies were half as competent as that.  I've never seen them do more than throw out a token unit or two.

Comment: @bwarner well essentially I was at war with the Aztec's, took thier capital and liberated Venice, then made peace. Then noticed Venice, and all the CSes on the continent, were at perma-war with Aztec, and the Aztecs were going to attack Venice. To help them defend I basically gave Venice *all* my waiting-to-be-upgraded units (and just build new ones) - so they had an army of 8-12 units or so - they easily deflected the Aztec attack and then went on the rampage, it was hilarious!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Normally a City-State will just raze any city that it managed to capture.

This could make giving a City-State lots of units a handy way to destroy a city or two in the vicinity of the City-States (remember, they don't roam far from their borders) without getting the world mad at you; you just have to ensure the CS stays at war with the target player until the desired target is destroyed.

However, for any city that it captures that *cannot* be razed - that is the original capital cities of the main Civ players and any other City-States - the capturing City-State simply takes the city as a puppet, leading to the odd scenario where a City-State player controls more than one city!

What they do not do is liberate the target if it could - for example, in my current game, Venice has just captured Stockholm, which was being held by the Aztecs. They didn't liberate Stockholm, just took it as a puppet, and so Venice now controls both cities (and the Stockholm player is still "out" of the game).

Comment: And thus a new civilization was born... Or is that a *two-city-state*? :)

Comment: There is a badge for accepting your own answer after it has some upvotes. If you don't have it already, this could be your chance.

Comment: @Olfan - there's also a 48hr time limit to ensure others have the change to respond first. I'm waiting on the time limit. And if you mean [Self Learner](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/badges/14/self-learner) I've already got that, seems *accepting* the answer isn't a requirement.

Comment: City states can capture/raze cities!? Im greece so I allied every city state I come acrossed, and Ottomans declared war on me, on of my allied city states are 5 hexes from one of the Ottomans cities, and my ally had the city surounded with troops, but did not attempt to even attack it once.

Comment: @NukesRus See my comments against the question for the circumstances which lead to me finding this out.

Answer (score 2):

Extreme example:
In a single game, I have had an allied  single city state capture 3 cities and hold all four for most of the game. This happened without my military.

France was on a small continent, which had 4 bordering city states on the coast. I was playing a pretty peaceful game and was allied to all 4 of those. When I DOWed France, those 4 city states started knocking down french cities, to my shock. Tyre captured Lyon, Paris (yep, the capital) and Marseille, with some help from others. It was pretty awesome to watch, and especially because I got bonus science from all those cities due to patronage :). They were not razed, I don't know why (Paris cause its a capital, but the other two I dunno). That was a while ago, a past patch may have changed the mechanic.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Take a look at this picture of one of my games as russia. Here's the story: I needed the king solomon's mine, but a city state took it, so i took the city state. Then everybody on my island hated me, INCLUDING Arabia, who was allied with all the city states on the island. Guess the rest of the story]

Take a look at this picture of one of my games as russia. Here's the story: I needed the king solomon's mine, but a city state took it, so i took the city state. Then everybody on my island hated me, INCLUDING Arabia, who was allied with all the city states on the island. Guess the rest of the story

Answer (score -1):

They capture the city and raze it to the ground.[image]

Comment: Dusseldorf would have been a city founded by Germany, whose capital is always Berlin.  It wouldn't fall under the category of cities that cannot be razed.